# Different color for each project in a workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have two projects in a workspace.

In each project I have some files that are named the same.

I sometimes edit one instead of the other.
Is it possible to distinguish the files depending on the project they are in - like having a color for each project?

Answer (score 0):

I use toolbar colors. For example, a solution with `client` and `server` sub-projects has different setting files to get green toolbar for one project and blue one for another. This really helps me. Setting files: [`file1`](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/client/.vscode/settings.json), [`file2`](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react/blob/master/server/.vscode/settings.json).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, but it says: "This setting cannot be applied now. It will be applied when you open this folder directly." Have you seen this?

Comment: I have a workspace file, just as you have - and "<name>.code-workspace" is in the root.

Comment: I use two instances of VS Code, one for each sub-project, when editing the files. That's when different colors apply. And open the workspace file when debugging both server and client simultaneously, in this case no different colors unfortunately.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clearing that - I will try to see what I can find and let you know